# Why does outputting non existent image completelly deletes session

Tags: php, image, session

I am developing a large site php, mysql, and js. But one particular script outpus a Mysql Table containing info and image locations, including the image if available. Images are optional.

Running it deletes all session information including the session file.

After long hours debugging (No errors, warning, notices, firebug or debbugin info gave a singlke hint) I found that this happens only when the image filename turns to be "./";

I have solved the issue by checking the filename before outputting the image. (but I can think on the many scripts I have written that fail to check on the image name.)

Nevertheless, that is an strange and unpredicted behavior, I would expect the script simply to show nothing, well a "Non existent image Box..."

No search proved helpful. Interestingly, the session deletion is not apparent on the calling page but in the next pages. Even when, as shown below, session is checked before ending the script. Caching writes to disk not allowed in my system.

Being there I ended up writing some debug scripts as below... (Re -reading session in the second script just for demo purpose, It is not neede, nor affects rtesult, it is ther just to show that apparently the session is still alive.

How to reproduce: (Tested on Chrome and Firefox)

Copy these scripts into you web servers, replace the image name to one of yours (optional) and run "SetSession.php". Everything looks OK, but reload "CheckSession.php", and you will notice session info is lost, In fact it was already lost when first run, but the script did not show it...

"SessionSet.php"

```
      <?php
      session_start();

      if (isset($_POST['SessionData']))
      {
           $_SESSION['SessionData'] = $_POST['SessionData'] ;
           echo "<br> SessionData value:  ",$_SESSION['SessionData'];
           echo "<br> Check Session <br>";
           ?>
                <form  method="get"  action="CheckSession.php">
                     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form> 
           <?php
      }
      else
      {
          echo '<br> Will place "SessionData" in $_SESSION["SessionData"] <br>';
           ?> 
            <form  method="post"  action="">
                <input type="text" name="SessionData" value="SessionData"  />  
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
           </form> 
           <?php     
      }

      ?>
```

"CheckSession.php"

```
          <?php
      session_start();

      // Display all errors
           error_reporting(E_ALL);
           ini_set("display_errors", 1);

      echo "<br>At Script Start <br> Session: <br>",   print_r($_SESSION),"<br><br><br>";

      // Sample image (>>>Change to an available image in your enviroment<<<)
      $ImgThumb ="images/RegAdd.png" ;

      // Outputting image
      ?> 
      Known Image: <IMG SRC="<?php echo $ImgThumb; ?>" alt="" /></td>

      <?php
      // checking session values again
      echo " <br> After ouputing known image Session: <br>", print_r($_SESSION),"<br><br><br>";



      // SECOND ASSIGNMENT Setting image value to offending value (v,gr ./ & /)
      $ImgThumb ="./" ;
      ?>
      Unknown image: <IMG SRC="<?php echo $ImgThumb; ?>" alt="" />
      <?php
      echo "<br>Session Array After outputting  $ImgThumb image: <br> ",print_r($_SESSION);

      ?>
```

Running the second script (From the first) produces the following output:

At Script Start
Session:
Array ( [SessionData] => SessionData ) 1

Known Image: {image}
After ouputing known image Session:
Array ( [SessionData] => SessionData ) 1

Unknown image:
Session Array After outputting ./ image:
Array ( [SessionData] => SessionData ) 1

---

Reloading the "CheckSession.php" script (Shown below) shows Data session has been lost, indeed session is deleted from disk.

At Script Start
Session:
Array ( ) 1

Known Image: {image}
After ouputing known image Session:
Array ( ) 1

Unknown image:
Session Array After outputting ./ image:
Array ( ) 1

---

Change the second assignment of $ImageTemp to any other thing, and Now it works...

Does any one Know why this happens? Or  is this is kind of those parser/program bugs. 
It is really strange an HTML image place holder is messing up session management  and a disk file.

Comment: just out of curiosity, have you tried this on different platforms (os/php versions/hardware)? This could help isolate it to a bug, or something specific to your system.

Comment: No, I am working from home this days. Apache 2.47, Mysql 5.6.15, php 5.5.8, Chrome 42.0.2357.65, Firefox 38.0.1, Windos 7 home premium, service pack 1. Will try on a remote server briefly...

Comment: Why the hell are you starting and stopping the session at all? This can easily lead to deadlocks if not done carefully. Also note that you allow the session data to change between session_write_close() and session_start(). Also, we'd need the info of what kind of data YOU see when running your script.

Comment: It was just part of testing, Indeed no changes to session values were made on second script where the openning and clossing were placed. Probably the only advise read elswhere was to "session_write_close" before movin on from a script...
Nevertheless, those had no effect, I am Editing question with shortened test, with no extra open/closures, and showing script results. Thanks for your input...

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproducce the issue on Linux servers (As most production sites are), so having a workaround for enviroments like mine as described in my question, seems to cover most cases. So I believe for practical purposes there is negligible bennefit of diggin up further if this is just my installation or a more common windows issue.
Thanks for all inputs on the issue.